# Difference between any n-digit number and a number which is a permutation of its digits always divisible by 3?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I have tried this out with many numbers and it seems to be true. Is it true no matter how many digits and if so, why?

I am using base 10 naturally but I wonder if there is a generalization, again, if it is true.

EDIT: Base 2 does not seem to have any obvious pattern. Hex (base 16) seems to also be divisible by 3 (same as base 10).

Comment: In base $b$ the difference is always divisible by $b-1$. So indeed, for $b=2$ this is not very remarkable.

Answer (score 0):

That's a nice observation. What you've observed is true always because the remainder when you divide a number by $3$ (or by $9$) is the same as the remainder when you divide the sum of its digits by $3$ (or by $9$). If you reverse a number you don't change the sum of its digits.

For more information you can read about [divisibility tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) at many websites.

As @WimC notes in a comment, this will work for any divisor of $b-1$ when you write numbers in base $b$.
$3$ works for hex since $3$ divides $16-1 = 15$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: I knew about the divisibility test for 3 but did not "put 2 and 2 together" to see how it was related. i guess the key is not just divisibility but that the sum of the digits and the number itself both have the same remainder when divided by 3, zero remainder being a special case. I am surprised that other bases have this same characteristic; i will try to figure out why. The permutation thing is interesting to me because that two numbers are related only by permuting the digits does not seem like a very significant relationship at first glance.

Comment: @BillDubuque This question may be a duplicate, but not of either linked questions, which only ask about the divisibility test.

Comment: @WimC I added a link for that (it was not clear where the OP was stuck before the above comment).